# Django _Categorize products

Tags: django

I want to show specific categories of items on a single page. Each category has a subheading and specific categories in the group.  Whenever i run the enve, everything is good but each subcategories output all the products, even the ones in other categories. How can i rectify this.

```
def waterProducts(request):
    category = request.POST.get('category')
    if category == None:
        products = Product.objects.order_by('-price').filter(is_published=True)
    else:
        products = Product.objects.filter(categoryname=category)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {
        'products': products,
        'categories': categories
    }

    return render(request, "products/WaterProductPage.html", context)
```

Above is my view.py files where i confirm if there is any category.

```
    <main style="background-image: url(images/waterrocks.jfif)">
        <section class="body-section">

            <div class="all-products">
                <!--Water coolers-->
                {%for category in categories%}
                <section class="main-products cooler">
                    <div class="upper-bar">
                        <div>
                            <h2>{{category.name}}</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sortby">
                            <span>Sort By: <select class="sort">
                                    <option value="highest">Highest Price</option>
                                    <option value="lowest">Lowest Price</option>
                                </select></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr />

                    <!--Single Products-wrap-->
                    <div class="specific-product-wrap specific-product-wrap-cooler">
                        {%if products%}
                        {%for product in products%}
                        <a href="{%url 'product' product.pk%}">
<div class="specific-single-product">
    <div class="product-image center">
        <img class="product-image-shape" src="{{product.image.url}}" alt="adamol Distilled" />
    </div>
    <div class="produc-descriptions">
        <h4 class="specific-product-title">{{product.title}}</h4>
        <p class="one-line-description"></p>
        <p class="price">Ksh.{{product.price}}</p>
        <button type="button" class="AddToCart">Add To Cart</button>
    </div>
</div>`
</a>
                        {%endfor%}
                        {%else%}
                        <p>No Product Lol</p>
                        {%endif%}

                    </div>
                </section>
                {%endfor%}
```

The above is my html template where i output each category with related product.

```
    class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=False, blank=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=True, null=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.TextField()
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The above code is for model.py where i declaire category as a foregn key.

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('waters', views.waterSamples, name='waters'),
    path('services', views.waterServices, name="services"),
    path('products', views.waterProducts, name='products'),
]
```

The above code is urls.py

I want the products to be shown like this...
on the same page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBd07.png)

Comment: Can you share the url paths that point to the `waterProducts` view? Together with a template where you ask for items of a specific category.

Comment: I don't want to show on different templates, i just want them to be on the same waterproduct page but in different categories

Comment: but can you share how you trigger your `waterProducts` view? Exactly with *what* URL?

Comment: with the given `path`s, how do you make a link that should show only items of a specific category?

Comment: I have shared the path in my recent edit on the original post, kindly have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fetch the products related to a `Category` with `category.product_set`, so:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <!-- … -->
    <h2>{{category.name}}</h2>
    <!-- … -->
    {% for product in category.product_set.all %}
        <a href="{%url 'product' product.pk %}">
        <!-- … -->
        <h4 class="specific-product-title">{{ product.title }}</h4>
        <!-- … -->
    {% empty %}
        <p>No Product Lol</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The `category.product_set.all` will retrieve all *related* `Product`s for a given `Category`, and thus not render all the ones.

If you only want to use `Product`s with `is_published=True` and ordered by `price`, you can use a `Prefetch` object:

from django.db.models import Prefetch

```
def waterProducts(request):
    categories = Category.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
        'product_set',
        queryset=Product.objects.filter(is_published=True).order_by('-price')
    ))
    context = {
        'categories': categories
    }
    return render(request, "products/WaterProductPage.html", context)
```

Comment: @JOSEPHMANIA: yes, there was a typo in the second (nested) `{% for %}` template tag.

Comment: This is the error am getting now                              
   'for' statements should have at least four words: for category.product_set.all

Comment: @JOSEPHMANIA: but that was fixed in the answer: it is `{% for product in category.product_set.all %}`, it was a typo that the `product in` was omitted.

Comment: Thanks so much it finally worked for me, have seen

Comment: thanks for helping, but i got a question, where do you get the 'product_set' you are fetching

Comment: @JOSEPHMANIA: If you construct a `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField` from model `A` to `B`, then Django automatically constructs a conceptual relation in reverse named `a_set` with `a` the name of the model in lowercase, so here `product_set`.

Comment: You are really saving me here thanks @Willem

Answer (score 0):

In your views file in the else part, shouldn't it be

```
products = Product.objects.filter(category=category)
```

Comment: Still fetching all the products from my db @Srishti